# Is it possible to access the Diamond guide in Visual Studio from the keyboard only?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I have taken to participating in mouseless Monday's and Friday's. I have set my windows float and dock tabs to hotkeys that allow me to pull them out or put them back in; however, I want to be able to choose which location to put the tabbed document in. I operate in landscape mode so I regularly have a bottom and a top window in visual studio. I would like to press a hotkey and send the selected document to that part of the diamond guide.  Anyone know a plugin or how I can do this?

Comment: [MouseKeys FTW!!!!!](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer)

Comment: That should do what I need create an answer with that and I'll accept it

Comment: Keep your title sensible please. No one is going to look for Visual Studio help in a post about “mouseless Mondays”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an entire article dedicated to [navigating the IDE using just the keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8hcfy22%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), with a section on docking windows and tabs using the diamond guide from the keyboard. So yes, it is possible, and you don't need a plugin for it:

> #### To move and dock tool windows from the keyboard
>
> 1. Navigate to the tool window you intend to move and give it focus.
> 2. On the **Window** menu, click **Dockable**.
> 3. Press **ALT** + **Space** and then choose **Move**.
>
>    The docking guide diamond appears.
> 4. Use the **ARROW** keys to move the window to a new location.
>
>    The mouse pointer moves with the window as you use the **ARROW** keys.
> 5. When you have reached the new location, use the **ARROW** keys to move the mouse pointer over the correct portion of the guide diamond.
>
>    An outline of the tool window appears in the new docking location.
> 6. Press **ENTER**.
>
>    The tool window snaps into place at the new docking location.

Alternatively, you can cheat by simply controlling the mouse pointer with the keyboard, through a nifty system accessibility feature called [MouseKeys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer).